# Azure WebApp location changing itself after deployment - Any fix?

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service

So I have two web apps and a service plan deployed under the same resource group.

```
$appservicePlanLocation = "West Europe"
$WebAppLocation1 = "Southeast Asia"
$WebAppLocation2 = "South Central Us"
```

The Service plan and Web Apps deploy fine with the correct locations.

30 seconds after deployment the locations of both web apps are changed to the same location as the app service plan....    Is there a solution to prevent this from happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Kind of "by design" feature. I wonder how could you chose a different location at first place. Of course when you deploy a website, you can only point it to a location where you have an app service plan. Because you deploy the sites in the plan. Physically. If you want websites in different locations you have to create app service plans in each location where you want deployment.